# How to use AMP mode for cortex a9 baremetal system?

Tags: bare-metal, cortex-a

Im working on a cycloneVsoc board with a cortex a9 duel core HPS.

I found out my load was too heavy for one core. And I researched a lot for duel core solutions. It turns out that there is little about how to use the duel core for cortex a9 in baremetal system.

I would like to use AMP mode for my board and run a baremetal/baremetal system.

I see my CPU0 as main CPU

and looking forward it to do the following job:

1. initial the system (include fpga image ,fpga bridges and interrupts, some service code and a simple scheduel tactic) ------- done
2. copy the CPU1 image (bin file with the same initial code, I don't know if it is necessary)  -------- don't know how to do it(Assambly ?)
3. tell the CPU1 its start address and shared RAM --------- could be done as a struct.
4. wake up the CPU1 from CPU0 ---------- no idea at all
5. getting into CPU state machine and let the machine run , two CPUs will repond the same FPGA IRQ signal and do different tasks. ---------- which is the main goal for my design.

The main issue is how to write the image file to the exact address (during debug and/or make it as one image).

And how to wake up the CPU1 from CPU0.

And if you find out my struct has any kind of potancial issues, please let me know.

Very thank you for your kindly help.

Thanks

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: "*I found out my load was too heavy for one core.*" -- Then you probably  would be better off finding a more powerful CPU than struggling with the complexities of a dual-core scheme.

Comment: It is a SoC(which means it is very expansive for me) and the producer dont offer software support for muti core baremetal system , so @sawdust your suggestion is not an option.Thank you for your reply though.